# Display multiple images from database

Tags: iphone, database, image, sqlite

I created local database for storing multiple images. I stored this file to Mainbundle. When i fetch the data only one image will be displaying from database. But i need to display all images under scrollview.

code:

```
NSMutableArray *appArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"App4.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
        }



        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM  App4Tbl";

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }

        //
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Myapp *Mylist = [[Myapp alloc]init];
            Mylist.appId = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
            Mylist.app = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            Mylist.rating = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];
            const char *raw = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 3);
            int rawLen = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 3);
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:raw length:rawLen];
            Mylist.photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            [appArray addObject:Mylist];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
    @finally {
        return appArray;
    }
```

Comment: are you getting all the values in the array ?

Comment: appArray how many values r in this

Comment: 3 images i stored in database

Comment: So when u fetch the images u wud fetch them in an array ... Now how many values do u get in the fetched array ?

Comment: I got one image from database